# How to get/put S3 encrypt object in nodejs with KMS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have some problem. I have few lambda functions, if i create script localy, and run it, all work, but if my code work on remote lambda i have error: access denied

```
S3Service.prototype.PutFile = function (bucket, key, body, type, callback) {

var s3 = new this.AWS.S3({region: awsConfig.region,"signatureVersion":"v4"});

var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: body,
    ContentType: type,
    ACL: 'public-read-write',
    ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
    SSEKMSKeyId: awsConfig.kmsKeyId
};

s3.putObject(params, function (err, res) {

    if (err) {
        callback(new InternalServerError(err));
    } else {
        callback(null);
    }
});
};

S3Service.prototype.GetFile = function (params, callback) {
var s3 = new this.AWS.S3({ region: awsConfig.region,"signatureVersion":"v4"});

s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {

    if (err) {
        callback(new InternalServerError(err));
    } else {

        callback(null, data.Body, data.ContentType);
    }
});
};
```

Bucket policy:

```
var policy = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",

    "Statement":[{
        "Sid":"DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads",
        "Effect":"Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action":["s3:PutObject"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::" + name + "/*",
        "Condition":{
                "StringNotEquals":{
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption":"aws:kms"
                }
           }
        }
    ]
};
```

Generating kms key:

```
 kms.createKey({ Description: 'qwe', KeyUsage: 'ENCRYPT_DECRYPT' }, function (err, data) {
       //var keyId = data.KeyMetadata.KeyId
});
```

How correctly put and get encrypting object to S3 with:  ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms'?

Comment: Can you please post the entire error message? I'm guessing there is more detailed error information in CloudWatch Logs than just "access denied".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That sounds like a problem with your lambda's role policy.  What is the lambda's role?

In particular, make sure it has something to the effect of the following:

```
"PolicyDocument": {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "s3:*"
    ],
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket",
      "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket/*"
    ]
  }, {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:Encrypt"
    ],
    "Resource": ["*"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: thx, i am fix the problem with GET object, but PUT object --- does not work. This problem state with PUT object method

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

1. Go to the S3 console, open the bucket and see what **KMS Key** is using for server-side encryption.
2. Go to the Lambda console, open your lambda function and see what is the **Execution role** .
3. Go to the KMS console, open the key from 1., scroll down to the **Key Users** section and add the execution role from 2.

[image: Add Key User]

Then you only need the `PutObject` permission and nothing else.